# Make this Javascript function only run on first match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make this function only add the var on the first match! (or run once)

```
  if ($.isFunction($.fn.flexslider)) {

        $("div.gallery-to-slideshow").each(function (index, item) {
            var gallery = new Gallery($(item));
        });
```

I tried adding :first in different place, but i'm quite new to Javascript and still struggling with understanding it!

Comment: How long you want the variable to survive for? Whatever's declared in the callback stays in the callback.

Comment: I just realized that! I need to stop it sooner somewhere!

Comment: Perhaps Jack's solution is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `first()` http://api.jquery.com/first/

```
    if ($.isFunction($.fn.flexslider)) {
       var gallery = new Gallery($("div.gallery-to-slideshow").first());
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var gallery = new Gallery($("div.gallery-to-slideshow:first"));
```

See here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7teT/)